# How to call a variable of a method in another method of the same class

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to access a variable of a method in another method of the SAME class and for some reason it prints nothing.

```
class Colors:
    def blue(self):
        var = "This is blue"
           
    def red(self):
        b = self.blue
        print(b.var)
```

I've also tried `print(self.blue.var)`.

Answer (score 10):

Local variables are, well, *local* to the scope of a function.  They don't even exist when the function is not currently being executed, so there is nothing to access.

If you want the variable to have a bigger scope, well, just give it a bigger scope:

```
def blue(self):
    self.var = "This is blue"

def red(self):
    print(self.var)
```

Answer (score 3):

Only one method runs at a time (in the simplest case, which is the default and the most common in most languages), and since local variables only exists while a function is running, i.e. get created when the function is called and destroyed when it returns, there is no such local during the execution of `red`.

Now, when you add concurrency, it's possible that `red` and `blue` run at the same time (but normally, you'd never know nor should you care). But `var` is still a **local** variable of `blue`, so even if there was some heck to get its value, doing so would be utterly insane and a crime against good practice. Sharing state between threads via globals is enough of a pitfall, no need to throw the locals in the mix as well.

What are you *really* trying to do? You propably want an instance variable (`self.var = ...`) or `return` something from `blue`.

Comment: I was of thinking of using an existing variable, save me coding time. I can work my way around this, but just wanted if it is possible what im trying to do in the initial code i posted.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables in a function/method cannot be accessed outside that function/method. To share state between methods, use an instance variable.

```
class Colors:
    def blue(self):
        self.var = "This is blue"

    def red(self):
        print(self.var)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of unexpected things going on here:

1. You are assigning `b` to `self.blue`, which is a function pointer to blue.
2. You have a scope issue, you want the following

   ```
   def blue(self):
       self.var = "This is blue"

   def red(self):
       print(self.var)
   ```

Or if you want to print something that blue is returning you do:

```
def blue(self):
    return "This is blue"

def red(self):
    print(self.blue())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I worked a way around it. made another local variable of the same value on the 2nd method.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer the helped you the most (click the green check mark by the answer).  This indicates to everyone that this is the solution you chose.